# Is there a way to determine filetype and read hand to buffer in one step?

Tags: ruby, file

Mahoro is a libmagic wrapper.  Right now my process for reading in a file is:

```
filetype = Mahoro.new.file(full_path)
File.open(full_path, get_access_string(filetype)) do |f|
```

The problem is that Mahoro seems to read the entire file, and not just the header strings.  So I get a profiling result like:

```
%self     total     self     wait    child    calls  name    
6.02      0.26     0.26     0.00     0.00        1  Mahoro#file
5.81      4.36     0.25     0.00     4.11        1  Parser#read_from_file
```

Each are taking .25 seconds, which implies that they are duplicating each other's work.  Is there a way to get the file as a string from libmagic?  That seems to be the only way to make this process more efficient.